# Python script execution directory changes when I execute outside of Console

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, system32

TLDR: I want to change the working directory of my script to the script file's location(instead of system32) when i run it by double clicking on it.
I have a really annoying problem I couldn't solve. I am building a python script that will take 4 text files as input and create some graphs and an excel sheet using these text files. I am going to pass my script to a friend who will copy this script into different folders and execute the script in those folders by just double-clicking on the script. The problem I am facing is when I execute my code out of cmd everything works fine. But if I double click on it, the directory my code is working changes automatically, and my program can't find the required 4 text files. I am attaching the required parts of my code below and also attaching some screenshots.
[ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JziCB.png)
[ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeqBm.png)

```
def fileOpenCheckLoad(fname):
    pl=list()
    try:
        fh=open(fname)
    except:
        print("ERROR:"+ fname +" is missing. Execution will terminate.")
        x=input("Press enter to quit.")
        quit()
    test1=fh.readline()
    test2=fh.readline()
    if test1[6]!=fname[5] and test2!='t x y\n' :
        print("ERROR: Check the contents of:"+ fname)
        x=input("Press enter to quit.")
        quit()
    count=0
    for lines in fh:
        count=count+1
        if count>2 :
            nums=lines.split()
            pl.append((float(nums[2]), float(nums[2])))
    tbr=(pl,count-2)
    return tbr

# main starts here.
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
# In this part we open and load files into the memory. If there is an error we terminate.
(pl1, count1)=fileOpenCheckLoad('point1.txt')
(pl2, count2)=fileOpenCheckLoad('point2.txt')
(pl3, count3)=fileOpenCheckLoad('point3.txt')
(pl4, count4)=fileOpenCheckLoad('point4.txt')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before calling `os.getcwd()`, insert this line:

```py
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

### Explanation

- `__file__` is a special variable in Python; as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), "`__file__` is the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded"
- `os.path.abspath` returns the absolute path to the input file or directory (I included this because depending on how you load up a Python file, sometimes `__file__` will be stored as a relative path, and absolute paths tend to be safer to work with)
- `os.path.dirname` returns the name of the directory which contains the input file (because `chdir` will return an error if we give it the name of a file, so we need to give it the name of the directory which contains the file)
- `os.chdir` changes the working directory

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Can you please explain how it works? Specifically "os.path.abspath(__file__)" this part.

Comment: @M.KeremAydın I'm glad it worked :) See my edit for an explanation (and feel free to accept my answer as the correct answer if it answered your original question)

Comment: Regarding the requirement for `abspath`, running the script with a relative path will result in a relative path in `__file__`. If it's just the script name (e.g. "main.py"), then `dirname` will return an empty string, and `chdir` will fail. Resolving the absolute path of `__file__` avoids this problem.